# Reload the view in iphone (in viewWillAppear)

Tags: iphone

I got a little app that has a button whose click is handled via

```
- (IBAction)click:(id)sender { }
```

Now, what I want is after click() runs, I want the view to refresh/reload itself, so that viewWillAppear() is re-called automatically.  Basically how the view originally appears.

Of course I can call viewWillAppear manually, but was wondering if I can get the framework to do it for me?

Comment: I'm setting up my view in viewWillAppear and after a button is clicked, I'd want that code to re-run so that it sets up new data on this view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

viewWillAppear is where to put code for when your view will appear, so it is more appropriate to put code that will be called repeatedly into another method like `-resetView`, which can then be called by both viewWillAppear and your click method.  You can then call `setNeedsDisplay` from within resetView.

```
-(void)resetView
{
    //reset your view components.
    [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear
{
    [self resetView];
}


- (IBAction)click:(id)sender
{
    [self resetView];
}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying, I guess it doesn't make sense to "get" viewWillAppear to get called while staring at the same view.